# Как передать аргумент из bash скрипта в файл .sql запросов

Tags: sql, bash

У меня есть два файла, один выполняет `bash` скрипт, второй `SQL` запросы, `bash` выполняет `sql`. Как мне передать переменную `USER` в файл `file.sql` и чтобы он вставился вместо строки `ARGUMENT`

**bash**

```
USER='ivan'
mysql=$(mysql -u user --password=abc "database" < file.sql;) # как здесь передать USER?
```

**file.sql**

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE login='ARGUMENT'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одним из простых способов может быть использование пользовательской переменной.

Содержимое файла запроса преобразуется в

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE login=@ARGUMENT;
```

Bash формирует строку

```
SET @ARGUMENT:='значение';
```

и добавляет её в начало передаваемого SQL-файла. Т.е. на MySQL-сервер для выполнения поступает такое содержимое:

```
SET @ARGUMENT:='значение';SELECT name FROM users WHERE login=@ARGUMENT;
```

---

Также можно попробовать передавать команду создания переменной и установления её значения в параметре *--init-command=str*. Что-то типа

```
mysql=$(mysql -u user --init-command="SET @ARGUMENT:='$USER';" --password=abc "database" < file.sql;)
```

Способ предпочтителен, если управляющий файл содержит несколько запросов, потому что init-команда будет выполняться для каждого подключения в случае обрыва/восстановления соединения, тогда как в первом способе переменная после обрыва и восстановления будет утрачена (не будет определена).